# Stracing by pid, child processes included

Tags: linux, fork, strace

I'm new to strace and I want to strace a forked child. Because I want to do this as a regular user, the process I want to strace by its pid needs to be a child of the tracing process (strace), so I need to fork twice. In bash:

```
( ( sleep 1; echo "I'm echoed from a child of strace" )& exec strace -p $! ) 
#the sleep is for giving strace time to attach itself
```

This all works, however I want to track the tracked process's children too and as soon as I add the `-f` switch to strace, I get an error:

```
( ( sleep 1; echo "I'm echoed from a child of strace" )& exec strace -fp $! ) 
#=> strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can trace all processes of your own user, not just the children of `strace`.

As to the problem that you are experiencing, you can rewrite the command as follows:

`strace -f bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Im echoed from a child of strace"'`

Comment: Not on ubuntu I can't. They have a freaking security policy for that. What you're doing though is creating a child of strace by running a giving it command argument. I don't have command argument for what I want to monitor. I want to monitor a branch in a larger suite. I can get to that branch via spawning with a parameter, but that'll go through all the setup code again. That's why I'd rather fork and strace by pid, but I also need to strace the processes invoked by the branch (use the -f switch) not just the branch itself. The bash code is just to demonstrate the problem in simple terms.

Comment: Being able to strace processes that are not your children is a security threat -- one hacked user-level application would be able to listen in on what other apps were doing and, for example, learn about passwords that way.

Comment: That can be disabled though -- see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#ptrace

Comment: @PSkocik The problem with the `No such process` error seems to be gone in strace 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not need `exec`, example here :

```
( ( sleep 3; sleep 10 & sleep 20 & sleep 30 )& strace -fp $! )
```

You will see that you do get the strace of all children processes :

```
...
[pid   166] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   174] <... nanosleep resumed> NULL) = 0
[pid   174] close(1)                    = 0
[pid   174] close(2)                    = 0
[pid   174] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid   174] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid   166] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 174
[pid   166] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   175] <... nanosleep resumed> NULL) = 0
[pid   175] close(1)                    = 0
[pid   175] close(2)                    = 0
...
```

`ps axf` output (with different PIDs):

```
  202 ?        S      0:00          \_ bash
  203 ?        S      0:00          |   \_ bash
  210 ?        S      0:00          |   |   \_ sleep 10
  211 ?        S      0:00          |   |   \_ sleep 20
  212 ?        S      0:00          |   |   \_ sleep 30
  204 ?        S      0:00          |   \_ strace -fp 203
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, on a user with no special permissions, and with the ptrace scope check enabled.

Comment: When run without exec 
` ( ( sleep 3; sleep 10 & sleep 20 & sleep 30 )& strace -fp $! )
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`
My `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` has `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1` (changing that is not an option).

Comment: That's strange, mine has `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1` too, and I created a test user just for this with no special permission whatsoever. I do get the same message as you using `exec` because it forks in a different way. Can you tell me your exact Ubuntu version so that I can switch my VM to that and try again?